# Visualizing multiple layouts in jung

Tags: java, layout, graph, visualization, jung

I am creating a RadialTreeLayout of a graph using [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/). Now I want to see one more  RadialTreeLayout of another graph (with same type of vertices and edges) as a part of the main layout.

The problem is not of uniting the two graphs (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165345/how-to-unite-two-graphs-in-jung)) but actually of visualizing a similar layout in the main window.

Few ways I thought of doing that, but not sure if they are feasible or not. e.g. to create one such node which actually is the layout (and can be seen with zooming in) or when one clicks on that node, another layout appears in a separate window.

Or are there existing ways to do that in JUNG already. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the demos.  I don't remember offhand which one, but at least one demonstrates visualization of multiple graphs.